# Configure 802.1Q VLAN on D-LINK switches

Tags: networking, vlan, d-link

I am looking for some help on configuring 2 D-LINK switches (DGS 1510-52X on one side and DGS 1210-52 on the other) for my network needs.

WAN LINKS on router are actually 2:

- First is WAN with NAT translation to company LAN network, having VLAN ID 1, Un-Tagged on port LAN1 on router going to Port 1 on SWITCH A
- Second is IPSec VPN link with NAT translation, which should not interfere with LAN and is used on some trusted devices and equipment. This one has VLAN ID 2 on router port 2, Un-Tagged and goes to Port 48 of SWITCH A

Both switches should be configured pretty much the same, using only Level 2 configuration and VLAN 802.1Q, having:

- Ports 1 to 39 for LAN computers
- Ports 40 to 48 for VPN devices

Only SWITCH A is connected to router, while SWITCH B is connected to SWITCH A using SPF connected Fiber optics cable from SW A port 52 to SW B port 52.

Here's the simple scheme: 
[2 Switchec with router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjEX1.jpg)

**Now, the goal is to have Un-Tagged devices on both switches, using LAN on ports 1-39 and VPN on ports 40-48.**

Could somebody help me configure those ports, as I have no idea how to properly Tag/Untag/Group ports on both switches. Thank you!

- ROUTER Port 1 -- LAN, VID 1, Untagged.
- ROUTER Port 2 -- VPN, VID 2, Tagged? Untagged?
  SW A Port 1 connected to Router Port 1
- SW A Ports 1-39 for LAN -- connected to ROUTER Port 1, Untagged
- SW A Ports 40-48 for VPN -- connected to ROUTER Port 2, Tagged?
- SW A Port 52 SPF fibre -- Accept any VID, Untagged?
  SW B is not directly connected to router, only Fiber optics cable
- SW B Ports 1-39 for LAN -- connected to ROUTER Port 1, Untagged
- SW B Ports 40-48 for VPN -- connected to ROUTER Port 2, Tagged?
- SW B Port 52 SPF fibre -- Accept any VID, Untagged?

Comment: You only tag frames on trunk ports. The tags allow the device on the other end of the trunk (usually a switch) to tell which frames belong to which VLAN. Frames should be untagged on access ports because there is traffic for only one VLAN on an access port.

Comment: Which means, only on SPF ports 52 on both switches I should select Tagged, right? As ports 52 on both switches are Fiber trunk connection.